# Spray.IO Stop http server with Http.Unbind

Tags: spray

I have an app built on spray 1.3.3 and I'm trying to stop http server by sending message.
Official documentation says:

> Stopping. To explicitly stop the server, send an Http.Unbind command to
>   the HttpListener instance (the ActorRef for this instance is available
>   as the sender of the Http.Bound confirmation event from when the
>   server was started).

Here is how i the start server:

```
(IO(Http) ? Http.Bind(httpListener, interface = iface, port = port)).map {
case m: Http.Bound => println(s"Success $iface:$port")
case fail : Http.CommandFailed => println(s"Bad try :(")
}
```

I tried to send message Http.Unbind to httpListener but with no success. Seems to be it's not that actor

May be i need to extract somehow sender ref of Http.Bound message? But how?

Here is my httpListener's head:

```
class MyHttpListener extends HttpServiceActor {

  import context.dispatcher

  def receive = runRoute(

    path("shutdown") {

      get {

        actors.httpListener ! Http.Unbind
        complete("Stopping server")

      }

    }
```

Anyway, i just want to send http request to /shutdown and have my application be down

Answer (score 0):

The `sender` of the `Bound` message should be the Spray listener, so when receiving that message you can capture it.

You did not post your full actor so this is a little different but I hope this helps.

```
class MyStarter extends Actor {

    // this will be the listener
    var myListener: ActorRef = _

    override def preStart(): Unit = {
      implicit val system = context.system
      IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(...)
    }

    override def receive: Receive = {
      case msg: Bound =>
        // when you receive the Bound message it was sent by the listener
        myListener = sender()
        ...
      case ... => ...
   }
}
```

Comment: I know, i don't understand how to capture when receiving.. Could you provide some code?